# Rigidbody circular movement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a 2D ball that has a force and moves in indeterminate direction, i need to make ball moves circular to right or left when user touches the screen, in relative to current direction without changing speed. How can i do that?

I tried this code, but other physics cannot affect the ball, because we are changing transform directly :

```
float angle = 0;
float radius = 1;

void FixedUpdate()
{
    angle += speed * Time.deltaTime;
    float x = center.x + Mathf.Cos(angle) * radius;
    float y = center.y + Mathf.Sin(angle) * radius;

    rigidbody.transform.position = new Vector3(x, y, 3);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the way physics does it:

Your touch position is kind of a gravitation center → Continuously assign a new direction using the same magnitude but in a new direction which stands in a 90° angle to the vector from center to the moving object and the rotation axis.

In code this might look like

```
public class Example : MonoBehaviour
{
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Camera _camera;

    [SerializeField] private Vector2 initialVelocity;    

    private bool doGravitation;
    private Vector2 centerPos;

    private void Awake()
    {
        if(!rb) rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        if(!_camera) _camera = Camera.main;

        rb.velocity = initialVelocity;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        // check for touch support otherwise use mouse as fallback
        // (for debugging on PC)
        if (Input.touchSupported)
        {
            // not touching or too many -> do nothing
            if (Input.touchCount != 1)
            {
                doGravitation = false;
                return;
            }

            var touchPosition = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
            centerPos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(touchPosition);
            doGravitation = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // mouse not pressed -> do nothing
            if (!Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            {
                doGravitation = false;
                return;
            }

            centerPos = _camera.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            doGravitation = true;
        }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if(!doGravitation) return;

        // get current magnitude
        var magnitude = rb.velocity.magnitude;

        // get vector center <- obj
        var gravityVector = centerPos - rb.position;

        // check whether left or right of target
        var left = Vector2.SignedAngle(rb.velocity, gravityVector) > 0;

        // get new vector which is 90° on gravityDirection 
        // and world Z (since 2D game)
        // normalize so it has magnitude = 1
        var newDirection = Vector3.Cross(gravityVector, Vector3.forward).normalized;

        // invert the newDirection in case user is touching right of movement direction
        if (!left) newDirection *= -1;

        // set new direction but keep speed(previously stored magnitude)
        rb.velocity = newDirection * magnitude;
    }
}
```

Also see:

- [`Input.GetTouch`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetTouch.html)
- [`Touch.position`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Touch-position.html)
- [`Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html)
- [`Vector2.SignedAngle`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector2.SignedAngle.html)
- [`Vector3.Cross`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Cross.html)

[image]

---

Note that this sometimes looks strange especially when touching in front of the ball since we force it onto a circle curve that might have a strange angle to the current movement. You can smooth that out but that's up to you ;)

Comment: Thanks @derHugo! such a perfect answer! you are pro man!
But there is a problem, the gravity radius increases smoothly when i keep touching, can you explain why?

Comment: Getting input on FixedUpdate will lead to bugs unless it is perfectly synchronous to Update, which it shouldn't ever reliably be, as that defeats the purpose. --- Also, there is no need to make a distinction between touch and mouse input in cases where only a single touch is supported like this one. Mouse handling alone will work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not making it move on its own axis the you have to attach it to a another body but do put the ball in the same position as the ball. You can the hide body then when you automate rotation it moves of the axis of the hidden body. Its the best way to achieve that without extra coding or the facing the quaternion problem.